# String with [[ to bidimensional array in nodejs

Tags: node.js, arrays

I have the following String, that returns from API

[ [ 1680373800000, "1.27860000", "1.28210000"] , [ 1680374700000, "1.27610000", "1.28000000", "0" ] ]

How to convert this to bidimensional Arrays in Nodejs? Thanks a lot :)

I tried differents solutions but I can not reach the solution.

in Node i don´t have a lot of experience, I try GSON in node

Comment: Your string is not valid JSON because of the comma after "1.28210000" in "1.28210000", ] which (at least on my system) gives an error when trying to use JSON.parse... Bearing in mind that there one more element in the second half, could you have mistyped the first half?

Comment: This string is the response of binance api when request the prices, i need to convert to bidimensional array

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) to get your array from a string.

Use [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your array in a String.

Comment: `JSON.parse` gives a syntax error for the OP's given data.

Comment: [
  [
    1682670600000,
    '0.42640000',
    '0.42720000',
    '0.42270000',
    '0.42390000',
    '1385834.00000000',
    1682671499999,
    '588825.66800000',
    1435,
    '631729.00000000',
    '268327.43430000',
    '0'
  ],
  [
    1682671500000,
    '0.42380000',
    '0.42510000',
    '0.42320000',
    '0.42460000',
    '338647.00000000',
    1682672399999,
    '143763.00510000',
    459,
    '154042.00000000',
    '65399.06090000',
    '0'
  ]]

Comment: I need bidimensional array where each [] is an element

Comment: @JulianIsaac Please edit your question with these additional details and some explanation of what they mean.